# CSS Circle DIV with a background not in scale 1:1

Tags: html, css, svg, hugo

I want to make a linguage picker for my Hugo website and I find this useful library: https://www.phoca.cz/cssflags/ that gives in pure svg and css all the flag of the world
Now I create my own subset of flag and in the css file each flag has something like that:

```
/* europe */
.eu {
 background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64, BUNCH OF DATA);
 width: 150%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The width and height could be not the same...so some flag has 150% as width and 100% for height and someone else different. What I want to achieve is perfect circle div of about 30px of diameter with at the center the flag. I try this code:

```
<div class="u-language">
            <a href="#" id="language-bar-invoker" class="u-icon-v1>
              <i class="eu g-rounded-20"></i>
            </a>
</div>
```

And the class g-rounded has this code:

```
.g-rounded-20 {
    border-radius: 20px!important;
}
```

but the result is a oval and not a circle! How can I solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a perfect circle of 30px diameter with the flag at the center:

```css
#language-bar-invoker i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 150%;
}

.eu {
  background-image: url(https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/flag-day.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="u-language">
    <a href="#" id="language-bar-invoker" class="u-icon-v1">
      <i class="eu"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

To achieve a circle, make sure the `height` and `width` are equal. Remember, height can only be set on `block` and `inline-block` elements. Then set `border-radius` to 50%.